# Saving plot with high resolution image

Tags: python, matplotlib

Since, i'm a newbie to python. I was trying to save a plot using **matplotlib** in python with the command `plt.savefig()`. 
The problem is that the image being save is low in resolution. Unable to read data points.

I was wondering if there is a way to save such figures in a very high resolution?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `savfig()` to export to an image file with specification of the dpi:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
plt.savefig('plot_name.png', dpi = 300)
```

You can choose needed dpi by yourself. I hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 6):

Use a resolution that uses specific sizing that is large :

```
 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(19.20,10.80))
```

produces 1080p for example and you can go much higher than this.

Answer (score 2):

```
savefig(fname, dpi=None, facecolor='w', edgecolor='w',
    orientation='portrait', papertype=None, format=None,
    transparent=False, bbox_inches=None, pad_inches=0.1,
    frameon=None)
```

you can use dpi=300 or other values